# CI/CD Pipeline using BitBucket and VertexAI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Has anyone tried building a CI/CD pipeline for a private repo on BitBucket and running on VertexAI (Google Cloud)? Or any similar use case?

Comment: Yes, I use private BitBucket repo and Cloud build. Not espacially VertexAI, all depends on your use case. Can you detail more?

Comment: Sure @guillaumeblaquiere, I have a bitbucket repo that has all the python code and pipeline code to be executed on the Vertex AI workbench from where I can also Pull and Push the code. I wanted to build a CI/CD pipeline for the same, as any new push happens on my `master` branch, the pipeline should run. Also, it should run at schedule intervals. Does that give you more clarification?

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a pipeline automatically on a code push, you have to connect your bitbucket server to Cloud Build. Like that, all the events will be get by Cloud Build and you will be able to do what you want.

To achieve that, you can follow the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/bitbucket/build-repos-from-bitbucket-server). If you have additional issues, let me know. As I said, I did it in my company ;)

---

About periodic run, you have to configure another trigger (than the push that you defined previously) and you can use either a manual invocation configuration or PubSub trigger.

In both cases, you will use Cloud Scheduler to either call the [Cloud Build REST API](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.triggers/run) to perform a manual invocation, or publish a PubSub message to the correct topic to trigger Cloud Build.